# Eclipse RCP 4: Change Colour of MToolItem Label

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, rcp, e4

I have a Direct Tool Item in a toolbar in my Eclipse E4 Application Model, and have added the "FORCE_TEXT" tag in order to allow the label to be displayed next to the tool item's icon. The text is displayed, but I want the text colour to be white instead of black. Is there a way I can do this? It doesn't seem like it's possible to change this text using CSS, and I can't find solutions online for how to do this.

[The FORCE_TEXT tag on my ToolItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grZqX.png)

[What the Tool Item looks like on my Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSgCC.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It appears that the CSS works for everything except the foreground color or the ToolBar. A possible workaround is to use an image containing the text. If you don't want to pre-render the images you could use a custom tool bar renderer to create the image.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will look into custom tool bar renderers, and hopefully that resolves this issue.